# Conditionally change row color on GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to change the background color of table rows based on the value of a cell within the row on a webpage. Basically, I want to a check whether a case has been closed by seeing if the value stored on the table is null. If there is a date stored on the table, I want the row to turn gray.

When I use this, it will turn all of the rows gray instead of the ones that don't have a null value. I've checked the values of the table and they do contain nulls. The values stored in the caseClosedDate column are data type dates.

```
protected void CaseList_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //table is generated through a stored procedure
    DataTable dt = mytable;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            //uses the column string name
            if(row["caseClosedDate"] != null)
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

edit
In case someone else is having a similar problem with the if statement, the table was populating the null values with "& nbsp;". 
**The final answer is:**

```
.case-closed { background-color:gray; }

}

protected void CaseList_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //table is generated through a stored procedure
    DataTable dt = mytable;

    if (e.Row.Cells[6].Text.Trim() != "&nbsp;")
    {
        e.Row.CssClass = "case-closed";
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Is `row["caseClosedDate"] != null` always satisfied? Perhaps it's an empty string when you're expecting null.
2. The better approach for what you're doing would be to set a class on the row and then set the color in CSS.  Separation of concerns...

Comment: Yes, I've created rows that will specifically be null but those are still showing a gray background. Wouldn't a css class still require a conditional check against the columns data?

Comment: Yes it would, but what if in the future you want to change the back color to green?  You have to change C# code.  It's a style concern...

Comment: I agree with @im1dermike here. Designs change all the time and you don't want to recompile for that. With that in mind, I updated my answer to give you the best of both worlds.

Comment: Thanks guys, that makes a lot of sense. I'll make the change in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop through the table, the values for the cells in the row are given to you in the even arguments.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    //Change the number here to refer to the column you are checking
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[1].Text))
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

However, as pointed out by @im1dermike in the comments, it's much preferable to use CSS to achieve the colouring. So create a new CSS class for the colour:

```
.case-closed { background-color: gray; }
```

And instead of setting the colour in code, just set the CSS class:

```
e.Row.CssClass = "case-closed";
```

Comment: @DaivdG I suppose this is obvious, but the condition is always satisfied when I change the code to 'if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[6].Text))'. I've checked my table to make sure I'm checking the correct column as well and there are null/empty values displayed on the webpage but it will still always change the background color of the row to gray. The only thing I can think that would cause that is the values being checked aren't null/empty, but the cells are empty and the database has them stored as null.

Comment: Also thanks for your help, I marked the answer correct due to it answering my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your OnRowDataBound Event if you are binding the data to the gridview.

```
if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "caseClosedDated") != null)
{
    e.Row.BackColor = Color.Gray;                
}
```